# Data not being displayed in Primefaces tab managed by viewscope spring bean

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I am using primefaces 5.1, jsf 2.2 (Mojarra), spring 4.1.6, prettyfaces 2.3.3.
I have a xhmtl which contains a tabview with more than one tab and spring managed view scope bean (**viewBean**).
The issue is values of the page (**view.xhmtl**) and that of zeroth tab is displayed. but the rest of the data in remaining tabs is not being displayed.ie, the value in **New Deals** tab is not being displayed.

When newDeals object of viewBean is made static, the value gets displayed.

I went through [jsf viewscoped bean - set values for every page(tabs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508322/jsf-viewscoped-bean-set-values-for-every-pagetabs),
[Using JSF with multiple tabs in one browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202604/using-jsf-with-multiple-tabs-in-one-browser), and would like to know if what i understood from the above links is correct. ie, we have to use session scope for a bean or page having multiple tabs in a view xhtml??

The project is uses prettyfaces for redirection.

**Update**
In http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes, it is mentioned that

> @ViewScoped: a bean in this scope lives as long as you're interacting with the same JSF view in the browser window/tab. It get created upon a HTTP request and get destroyed once you postback to a different view.

So how come the (1st to last) tab's data is not loaded in a page consisting of a tabview (with multiple tabs) while the 0th tab's data is loaded?

Code is as belows

List.xhmtl

```
<p:dataScroller value="#{listBean.pdtVOList}" var="pdt">
   <p:commandLink value="#{pdt.name}" action="#{viewBean.viewPdtFrmList(pdt.id)}" ></p:commandLink>
</p:dataScroller>
```

ListBean

```
@Scope("view")
@Component
public class ListBean implements Serializable {
  private List<Product> pdtVOList; //include getters and setters
  public void fillPage() {
    pdtVOList = ownerService.fillProductList(); //gets all product from db
  }

}
```

viewBean is

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {
   private static Product pdt = new Product();
   private NewDeals newDeals = new NewDeals();
   //include getter and setters

   public void fillPage() {
      //is Empty
   }
   public void viewPdtFrmList(String pdtIdStr) {
      pdt = new Product();
    //set pdt values
      setPdt(getPdtValuesFromDB(pdtIdStr));

      newDeals = pdtRepository.getNewDealsCOmbo();

      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect("/pdt/view");

   }

   public getPdtValuesFromDB(String pdtIdStr) {
     //get values from database
     pdt = pdtRepository.getValuesFromDB(Integer.parseInt(pdtIdStr));
   }
}
```

Product Model

```
private int id;
private String name; //Include getter and setter
```

pdtView.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="#{viewBean.pdt.id}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{viewBean.pdt.name}"/>
<p:tabView id="tabview" style="width:100%;float:right;">
    <p:tab id="clientPricing" title=" Pricing">
        <h:outputText value="#{viewBean.pdt.price}"/>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="New Deals">
        <h:outputText value="#{viewBean.newDeals.name}"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

prettyconfig.xml

```
<url-mapping id="ownerandpetsview"> 
    <pattern value="/pdt/view" />          
    <view-id value="/WEB-INF/views/pdtView.xhtml" />
 </url-mapping>
```

web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param
```

Comment: since its view bean it loses its state when you press tab and instance `newDeals` is instantiated again.

Comment: so you mean that on tabchange i should reinitialze the newdeals object..right?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work this by viewparam, have a viewparam in `pdtView.xhtml`

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="key" value="#{viewBean.key}"/>
    </f:metadata>
```

and initilize product from the key

```
    @Component
    @Scope("view")
    public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

        private static Product pdt = new Product();
        private NewDeals newDeals = new NewDeals();
        //include getter and setters

        public String key;

        public void fillPage() {
            //is Empty
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void loadProduct () {
          getPdtValuesFromDB(key);
        }

        public void viewPdtFrmList(String pdtIdStr) {
            pdt = new Product();
            //set pdt values
            setPdt(getPdtValuesFromDB(pdtIdStr));

            newDeals = pdtRepository.getNewDealsCOmbo();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect("/pdt/view");

        }

        public getPdtValuesFromDB(String pdtIdStr) {
            //get values from database
            pdt = pdtRepository.getValuesFromDB(Integer.parseInt(pdtIdStr));
        }
    }
```

finally from the `list.xhtml` you need to call the view page with parameter like `view.xhtml?key=pdt.id`